# Provide preview for custom files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I've developed a Google Drive app called VideoNot.es (http://videonot.es).

When users try to open files directly from Drive, without installing the Chrome app, it shows up an overlay saying "No preview". In consequence, they don't really understand how to open it with my app and I have to explain that they need to go to Manage Apps and make VideoNot.es the default app for this kind of files.[image]

How can I improve this flow?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good question Arnaud. Sorry I have no good answer for you. We are working on it, and we are really keen to have all these preview flows fixed to ensure users can easily install your app and get going. Please stay tuned.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for the prompt answer. We are looking forward to see this flow improved!

Answer (score 0):

Provide a file thumbnail, it should appear on the file preview if Google Drive can't render a thumbnail itself. Details are on https://developers.google.com/drive/file at the "Uploading thumbnails" section.